# When I try to render, nothing happens

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

When I press render, the render window opens but nothing appears in it. I have been using blender for a long time now and this has never happened before. I have checked that I am using the right render layer and checked that nothing is wrong in the compositor. This happens in Eevee and cycles. Help me!

Comment: this happens even with new default file? Open completely new file, just a cube and it still won't render?

Comment: have you loaded a movie in the Video Editor?

Comment: The default cube renders fine for some reason
Ill restart my computer and see if that helps at all

Comment: Any chance you deleted your camera, or it's being obscured by some (possibly viewport-hidden) object?

Comment: Nope, the camera is definitely there. This problem persists between multiple scenes, I have an ocean modifier in my scene and any resolution above ten does this, which is weird because my computer is pretty beefy